# Store numbers in mysql and change that number to something?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm thinking adding a number to a row, and in an array (or something) i can declare what it is.

Like this:

```
mySQL table
id type duration
1   2      5
2   3      4
3   6      10

PHP array or something
type 2 = jumping
type 3 = biking
type 6 = painting
```

This way it will be easier to add, or remove a "type".
But sorry, i have no idea how to do this.

The effect I'm looking for is to display

```
Johan was jumping for 5 minuts
Johan was biking for 4 minuts
Johan was painting for 10 minuts
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Add to another table then you just join the 2 in a query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to safe everything to a DB instead of hard-coding it in your code. So taking your table as basis:

```
Table: t1
id type duration
1   2      5
2   3      4
3   6      10

Table: t2
type_id whatever
2       jumping
3       biking
6       painting
```

You could use a SQL-Join to combine those two tables:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t2.whatever, t1.duration
FROM t1
JOIN t2
     ON t1.type = t2.type_id
```

will produce

```
1   jumping   5
2   biking    4
....
```

Comment: How do i get the uid from t1?

Comment: which uid?
If you want to add the type-field of t1 to your resultset just append ``t1.type`` to the SELECT like ``SELECT t1.type, t1.id, t2. ...``